# How to interact with server when app is running in background ionic-cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I'm using **cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation** for fetching the location in the background even when the app is not running in the foreground. What I want to achieve is to get the coordinates of the user and send it or post it to the server for real-time location tracking and updating the DB.
I think the problem is location points are updating in the background but the data is not posted to the server.
Is there any way to interact with the server when the app is not in the foreground.

**This is my code:**

```
// Background Tracking
let config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
desiredAccuracy: 0,
stationaryRadius: 20,
distanceFilter: 10,
debug: true,
interval: 2000
};

this.backgroundGeolocation
.configure(config)
.subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

console.log('BackgroundGeolocation: ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);

// Run update inside of Angular's zone
this.zone.run(() => {
this.lat = location.latitude;
this.lng = location.longitude;
});

// Server interaction to POST location coordinates.

}, (err) => {

console.log("ERROR in config", err);

});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Two things: why do you need running your code in “zone” here? If your app has no UI since it is in background you should not care about adding zone. Second: did you try to add code to post to server there? Does it work? If not what errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Update your configuration to

```
let config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
desiredAccuracy: 0,
stationaryRadius: 20,
distanceFilter: 10,
debug: true,
interval: 2000,
 // Android
startForeground: true,
stopOnStillActivity: false

//IOS
 pauseLocationUpdates: false,
saveBatteryOnBackground: false,

}
```